# API request doesn't receive access token after page refresh in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jsx, react-context

I'm making a React application using the Pet-finder API. I store my access token inside a context. When i render a specific animals page it renders fine (most of the time, assuming because of the same problem), but when i refresh the page it throws an axios error with the `status: 401` for which the API docs refer as `Access was denied due to invalid credentials`. When i check the headers it contains `Authorization: "undefined undefined"` where the token type and the token itself is supposed to be.

The partial fix i have found is adding `token` to the dependency array of the useEffect I use to make the request but the error still pops up in the console on refresh and the data loads right after. Also this is the only page I'm making a request on immediately after rendering (maybe it has something to do with the issue).

TokenContext.jsx

```
const TokenContext = createContext();

export const TokenProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState({});
  let location = useLocation();

  const fetchToken = async () => {
    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/fetchToken")
      .then((res) => {
        const newToken = {
          token: res.data.access_token,
          tokenType: res.data.token_type,
          expires: new Date().getTime() + res.data.expires_in * 1000,
        };

        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(newToken));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const foundToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));

    if (!foundToken || token.expires - new Date().getTime() < 10) {
      fetchToken();
    } else {
      setToken(foundToken);
    }
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return (
    <TokenContext.Provider value={{ token }}>{children}</TokenContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default TokenContext;
```

Pet.jsx

```
const Pet = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { token } = useContext(TokenContext);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [pet, setPet] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    petFinderApi
      .get(`/animals/${id}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${token.tokenType} ${token.token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setPet(res.data.animal);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [token]);

  if (!pet) {
    return (
      isLoading ?? (
        //Spinner renders here
      )
    );
  } else {
    return (
//Stuff will render here
)
  }
};

export default Pet;
```

Comment: On refreshing the page context will lost data because its not storing in any storage permanently. You can store your token in browser memory(localstorage or cookie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token is initially an empty object:

`const [token, setToken] = useState({});`

While you are fetching the token in the background, the token value is passed to `TokenContext`:

`<TokenContext.Provider value={{ token }}>{children}</TokenContext.Provider>`

During the first rendering, the following `useEffect` will still be executed.

```
useEffect(() => {
// ...
}, [token]); // {}
```

Try adding a check to see if token is undefined/empty object in the useEffect?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    
    if(token && Object.keys(token).length !== 0){
       // grab a pet
    }
  }, [token]);
```

---

Instead of writing

```
  if (!pet) {
    return (
      isLoading ?? (
        //Spinner renders here
      )
    );
```

You can also use [React.Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) to display the spinner.

e.g.

```
import { Suspense } from 'react';

//... other code

return (
   <Suspense fallback={<MySpinner />}>
      <MyComponentToDisplayWhenPetIsFetched pet={pet} />
   </Suspense>
);
```

This tutorial explains [Suspense](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-suspense-data-fetching/) pretty well